Possible values of the integral of the function with the information of derivative
Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ denote some continuously differentiable function such that $f '(x)$ is continuous and $ \int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$. If $\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|=24$, then what are some/all of the possible values for $|\int_0^xf(t)dt|$ given $x\in[0,1]$?
I tried plotting the graphs $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$, checking the areas (one observation I had was that the positive area and negative area should be equal for $f(x)$ over $[0,1]$). And from this, I was able to derive a maximum value for $f '(x)$, but I can't find any way to make much use of it. I suspect that my approach to this question is overly complicated, and that there is an easier route involving Mean Value Theorem.

I suspect that the maximum is obtained by $f(x) = 24(x-1/2)$ at $x =1/2$ which yields a value of $6$ so this may lead to some potential proofs by comparison

@whpowell96 you mean maximum value of this function in [0,1] should be 12 at x=1 and how did you get that function?

Sorry, I meant the maximum of $|\int_0^x f(x)dx|$. This choice of $f$ attains the maximum derivative value everywhere so it seems like it might be extremal

I picked the function whose derivative was the maximum possible that still integrated to zero. The only choices are this or its negative
